# How to implement horizontal scroll for toolbar in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

```
        LinearLayout standardtoolbar = new LinearLayout(context);
        standardtoolbar.setMinimumWidth(10);
        standardtoolbar.setMinimumHeight(50);
        Bitmap toolbarBackgroundImage = SkinManager.getInstance().getImageBitmap("BarBackground");
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(toolbarBackgroundImage);
        standardtoolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpstandardtool = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(5, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpstandardtool.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        toolbarLayout.addView(standardtoolbar, 0);
        /*toolbarLayout.getScrollX();
        toolbarLayout.scrollBy(5, 0);
        toolbarLayout.setScrollBarStyle(0);
        */    
        ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity());
        scroll.addView(toolbarLayout);
```

the scroll view is not working for the given layout. The commented code was written for horizontal scroll view. But its not working.

Comment: toolbarLayout..setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

Answer (score 2):

in your xml file  **example.xml**

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content>  

   <LinearLayout android:id="layout" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

   </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**in java code**

```
LinearLayout standardtoolbar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
.
.
.
layout.addView(standardtoolbar, 0);
```